# Question Links statistic

Tags: feature-request, questions

Is it possible to add a number of links to the question page available on Stack Exchange sites that has a link to this question. For example

I can find on the page

> asked   1 year ago
>
> viewed  116 times
>
> active 1 year ago
>
> **linked  xxxx times**

---

I would be nice if it has a `href` to the page where you can list all links and their date of creation, and could navigate to the corresponding page which contains this link.

This feature could give a presentation of the background activity of the question.

Comment: But the linked questions are already listed and when you click the see more link you get [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/6209730?lq=1) ... unless I misunderstand what you want....

Comment: @rene On the page I can see only questions, but I want to see links, who created a link, date of creation, type of link (comment, question, answer), with possibility sort them by date.

Comment: OK, I have a rough [sede query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/426960). Is that what you mean?

Comment: @rene The query is rough, duplicates, missing data, wrong where clause, etc., it could be a starting point. However, you need to add it to SO and design a new page to show results.

Comment: Yeah, not all data is there in SEDE and the outer joins are based on guesses instead of proper foreign keys, I reduced some of the duplicates though. I doubt however if that data you'll need for such page is available in the full-blown production db.

Comment: That's interesting, but I'd rather a statistic like ***shared N times***.